# Error in loading DLL during missing reference removing

Tags: excel, vba, dll, reference

I need to fix (by vba excel code) error incurring by missing reference.
I use this code but the script stop with the error "Error in loading DLL" when find the missing reference and try to remove it.

```
Sub RemoveReferences()
Dim VBAEditor As VBIDE.VBE
Dim vbProj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim chkRef As VBIDE.Reference

Set VBAEditor = Application.VBE
Set vbProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

For Each chkRef In vbProj.References
    If chkRef.IsBroken Then
    'MsgBox "Trovata una libreria mancante. Tento la sistemazione."
        vbProj.References.Remove chkRef
    End If
Next

Set vbProj = Nothing
Set VBAEditor = Nothing
End Sub
```

The scrip return the "Error in loading DLL" in the row vbProj.References.Remove chkRef. 
Have you got an idea for fix this error? I'va just activate "Trust access to the VBA project object mode".

This is the screenshot of the error.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6BaO.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I do it? How can I rename the referenced file?

Comment: I assume you already have a reference to "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility x.x" to use `VBIDE`. Do you?

Comment: Exactly I've just have a reference to "Microsoft Application ..."

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong to write. I've already ticked "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility x.x".